# What is a deterministic, non-negative, and Borel-measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory, function

May I know the intuitive understanding of a deterministic, non-negative, and Borel-measurable function?

Especially, I am not sure what the 'deterministic' and 'Borel-measurable' functions are.

Could you please help me understand this in the most easiest way?

Comment: It would help to know the context of your apparent quotation.  In particular, it isn't at all evident what someone might mean by a "non-deterministic ... Borel-measurable function," so the intended meaning of "deterministic" is obscure.  Does this phrase come from some well-regarded paper or text or is it perhaps some throwaway passage from somebody's blog?  Perhaps it's part of a treatise on stochastic processes where the authors are concerned with distinguishing functions from stochastic processes (which are thought of as being "random functions")?

Comment: A well regarded paper

Comment: Which one?  Could you supply a reference?  As I'm trying to indicate, "deterministic" is a vague term whose interpretation needs context.

Comment: Furman and Zitikis(2008)  "Weighted risk capital allocations" Insurance: Mathematics and Economics

Comment: Thank you.  As far as I can tell, their use of "deterministic" is superfluous.  The adjective "non-negative" also adds nothing, because the function $w$ has already been declared to take values in $[0,\infty)$. Thus, only "Borel-measurable" requires any explanation.  Have you [searched our site?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Borel+measurable)